# Zeroes Skipping in Hexadecimal Printing

Tags: c, cryptography, char

The code mentioned below generates keys using the time.h library provided by C.
I am trying to print the keys byte by byte using the variable `a` but the main issue im facing is when i copy the value from `key[i]` to `a` it skips zeroes because i am using `%.2x` while printing `key[i]` but not in `a`. i want to store the byte in `a` with the zero too , as printed for `key[i]` for a single byte.
Secondly, I want to know how can I concatenate `a` after 16 iterations in a single string `finalKey`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#define KEYSIZE 16

typedef unsigned char BYTE;

void main()
{
//2018-04-17 23:08:49
//TOTAL SECONDS  = 1,524,006,529
long long int total_seconds = 1524006529;


char finalKey[KEYSIZE];
int i;
char key[KEYSIZE];
int x = 0;
printf("%lld",total_seconds);


for(x = 0;x<7200;x++){
srand (total_seconds--);

    //KEYSIZE = 16 so 16 Iterations each time prints a hexadecimal 
    //HAVE TO STORE WHOLE KEY in finalKey after 16 iterations

    for (i = 0; i< KEYSIZE; i++){

        key[i] = rand()%256;
        BYTE a;


        // printf("%.2x", (unsigned char)key[i]);
        // PRINTS = >  4dd733c6bc3d355ca2f90c4811d2960c

        a = (key[i]&0xFF);
        printf("%x",a);
        // PRINTS =>  4dd733c6bc3d355ca2f9c4811d296c ( removes 0 )


    }

    // system("openssl enc aes-128-cbc -d -in plaintext.txt -out output.txt -k " + finalKey +" -iv 09080706050403020100A2B2C2D2E2F2");

    printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes but I want to store it in a like that, not just print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to print at least two characters with leading zeros filled in.  So use this:

```
printf("%02x",a);
```

The field width of `2` specifies that the  at least two characters should be printed, and the `0` flag means the result should be left-padded with zeros.

Comment: Yes but I want to store it in a like that, not just print.

Comment: Oh okay, Can you help me with my second question?

Comment: @BlueseaDigitalme Use `sprintf` to print the formatted text to the string, starting at a different offset on each loop iteration.  You'll need to increase the size of the string to at least `2*KEYSIZE+1` to fit all the characters plus the terminating null byte.

Comment: Consider me a complete noob, can you elaborate please.